# Function References and lambdas

Tags: kotlin

I'm facing a compile error when trying to use lambdas / function references with kotlin:

```
class Foo {

    fun getFilteredList(){
        val numbers = listOf(1, 2, 3)
        numbers.filter(::isOdd) // prints [1, 3]
    }

    fun isOdd(x: Int): Boolean = x % 2 != 0

}
```

But I get a compile time error saying a type mismatch:

> Error:(18, 16) Gradle: Type inference failed: inline fun 
>   kotlin.Iterable.filter(predicate: (T) -> kotlin.Boolean):
>   kotlin.List cannot be applied to receiver: kotlin.List 
>   arguments: (kotlin.reflect.KFunction2) Error:(18, 23) Gradle: Type mismatch: inferred type
>   is kotlin.reflect.KFunction2 but
>   (kotlin.Int) -> ??? was expected Error:(18, 23) Gradle: Type mismatch:
>   inferred type is kotlin.reflect.KFunction2 but (kotlin.Int) -> kotlin.Boolean was expected
>   Error:(18, 25) Gradle: Left-hand side of a callable reference with a
>   receiver parameter cannot be empty. Please specify the type of the
>   receiver before '::' explicitly

I'm not sure what the error is nor what type I should specify explicitly before '::'

Another question:
Can I use another objects function as reference in kotlin? Something like this:

```
class Bar {
    fun isOdd(x: Int): Boolean = x % 2 != 0
}

class Foo {

    fun getFilteredList(){
        val bar = Bar()
        val numbers = listOf(1, 2, 3)
        numbers.filter(bar::isOdd) // Use Bar's method
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

On the second example: yes, the [bound function reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#bound-function-and-property-references-since-11) syntax is supported since Kotlin 1.1, so you can write `bar::isOdd` similarly to Java.

In the first example, the error is trying to say that `isOdd` is in fact a function of two parameters (of types `Foo` and `Int`), and passing a function taking two parameters as an argument whose type is function of one parameter is not allowed. To make the example compile, you can make `isOdd` a top-level or a local function, which would make it a function of one parameter of type `Int`. Or, if you use Kotlin 1.1+, use the bound function reference syntax and simply write `this::isOdd`.

Comment: Would be handy, because of testablity. If I pass a lambda directly there is no real way to unit test the lambda itself. Hence I was looking for a way to use a function, since a function itself is unit testable. As far as I see you can also define a function in a class like this: `class Foo{ val isOdd = fun(i : Int) : Boolean { return i % 2 != 0 }  } ` . Then in the class Foo you can pass `isOdd` instead of a lambda and isOdd will still be unit testable. However, this seems to be a workaround. Would be pretty nice to have similar function references as java 8 just for unit testing

Comment: @udalov What you mean by a local function? How do you create one? By a lambda?

Comment: A local function is the one declared within another function, see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#local-functions

Answer (score 7):

That's funny. "Java strikes back". Haha

Your problem is simple: you declared `isOdd` in class `Foo`, right? Then it is not a **function**, but a **method**. Which means that it requires an instance of `Foo` to be passed in (the `this` reference) - that's why it is a function of 2 parameters: `Foo.(Int) -> Boolean`. And the syntax error shows that - a reference to a method looks like `Foo::isOdd`.

<s>Anyway, declaring a non-static method which does not use the object is an antipattern even in Java, don't you agree?</s>

The problem might be solved by declaring a free function without a class or by making it an extension: `fun Int.isOdd()`

P.S. Regarding your second question - that feature is not supported yet.

Comment: I have to disagree about the anti-pattern. isOdd() could be an overridable method, and the class could use it to implement the template pattern. Java supports such method references just fine, and I think Kotlin should support it. I see that as a step back when coming from pure Java 8. Same as not being able to use a lambda to implement a functional interface defined in Kotlin: not being able to name things is a step backward to me. And the difference between Java interfaces and Kotlin interfaces is bizarre.

Comment: @nizet OK, you have your point. I agree that kotlin is a bit strange with functional references. As someone said, functions are not first-class citizens, but lambdas are. I believe that Kotlin must support not less than Java

Comment: Functions in Kotlin are first class citizens.  The issue here is that a function that has two parameters (receiver, param0) cannot be used in place of one that expects only one parameter.  What you are looking for there is a method closure, which can turn a method into a function by carrying the reference to the receiver into the call.    The code could easily do this by passing in a lambda that calls the class method.  That would close on the instance of the class as the receiver.  Later Kotlin might do this automatically.